# Wireless Distribution for iPad app for CentOS

Tags: ipad, centos, plist, wireless, centos6

I am attempting to distribute an iPad application wirelessly over an IP address using a CentOS 6 server. I've done this on a GoDaddy web hosting account and it worked just fine. I have the plist and ipa file in there, and I linked to the plist as so:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=http://(ipAddress)/apps/theapp.plist
```

However when I click on the link, absolutely nothing happens.  I already added the MIME lists for ipa and plist to the mime.type file, and restarted the server.

```
application/octet-stream ipa

text/xml plist
```

Still nothing. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

With enterprise / in house distribution, the release version has to be signed with the same profile as is used in the archive / distribution process

Comment: Yes, I did that. This works fine on my GoDaddy webhosting account. I transfered the same files over to a dedicated server and now it doesn't work.

Comment: Just wondering if you got this working.  I'm having the same problems and still cannot figure this out.  Thanks.

Comment: I fixed. the problem is https. I change it to http. everything is fine.